# We are a panel of five people

Tags: riddle

Well, hello hello hello hello hello hello hello, and welcome to the Puzzling Stack Exchange, or 大家们好, as they say in Chinese. Tonight we'll start with a riddle to see if you can find out who we are.

Sitting where I sit is a man who is not small, but if I were, I would be an insignificant little thing.
To my left is a man who doesn't empty gas giants in our Solar System but does the opposite,
To his left is the comedian who killed Goliath (and Webb).
Two seats to my right is an invoice that surrounds a motte,
And directly to my right is that joker whose name I always pronounce like the "e" isn't there.

Fingers on buzzers please. Who are we, and what episode is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are, from left to right (facing the panel):

> Bill Bailey, Alan Davies, Stephen Fry, Phill Jupitus, and David Mitchell

You are the

> Panel from QI, and this is episode 32, "Corby"

Explanations:

> **Bill Bailey**: Invoice = Bill, Motte is a reference to a [motte-and-bailey castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motte-and-bailey_castle).
> **Alan Davies**: I think joker is just a generic reference to him being a comedian, and Stephen Fry always pronounces his last name like "Davis".
> **Stephen Fry**: I think "insignificant little thing" is meant to reference the phrase "small fry".
> **Phill Jupitus**: Rather than "empty gas giants" he will "fill Jupiters". Eh, ehhh?
> **David Mitchell**: This was the one that cracked the whole thing for me, because I'm a huge fan. "Killed Goliath" = David, obviously, and David Mitchell was a double act with Robert Webb for a long time, with a couple shows and even their own [Wikipedia article!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitchell_and_Webb)

Comment: Perfect. Everything is correct.

Comment: @JoeZ. In researching which episode this was, I found a youtube playlist with all of the QI episodes in which David Mitchell appears, which has provided several hours of entertainment for me this evening. So thanks for your part in that happening!

Comment: Actually, there is one thing in your explanation that doesn't quite match... Fry called Alan a joker because he usually uses some endearing insult to introduce him in the later seasons. (By season C they hadn't done that yet, but soon enough they will.)